# iOS MKMapKit init with location that is not user location

Tags: ios5, mkmapview

I know this is probably something simple but I can't seem to find anything on this through the internet:

All I want to do is load a map with some latitude and longitude coordinates. If someone could drop a snippet or link me to a resource I'd appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    float zoom;


    CLLocationCoordinate2D longPointLightLocation;
    //the coords for Long Point Lighthouse, Provincetown, MA
    longPointLightLocation.latitude = 42.033126;
    longPointLightLocation.longitude = -70.168621;
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:longPointLightLocation animated:NO];
    zoomLocation = longPointLightLocation;
    zoom = 50;

    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, zoom*METERS_PER_MILE, zoom*METERS_PER_MILE);
    [mapView setRegion:[mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion] animated:NO];
```

Comment: I just figured it out but I'm giving you the credit for it regardless, it'll be good to have this out there for other people. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! And I just got side track by looking up your user name, was familiar, now I know. wow...

Comment: Depends on what you found, it's actually a reference to a Phillip Glass song (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOEDsZbR6jE), the song is in reference to the PI projects but I came across it from Glass first.

Comment: zoomLocation - is that property of mapView? is zoom a float?

Comment: Glass is (or was) all about repetitive sounds, some of his stuff is hard to listen to (definitely not make out music : D) but sometimes it works if you want to zone out on work.

Comment: Ha, just reread my code. zoomLocation isn't really needed... I'll fix it in my app.